# How to Query Start Of Quarter and End Of Quarter in bigquery, h2, hadoop and prestoSQL Databases?

Tags: hadoop, google-bigquery, h2, presto

I would like to write query for the Start of Quarter and End of Quarter for any date with timestamp.
For eg if I pass current timestamp it should return me the corresponding date's quater first day (with timestamp 00:00:00) and quarter last day (with timestamp 23:59:59)

How to achieve the same for Couchbase, BigQuery, h2, Hadoop etc?

Thanks

Comment: for BigQuery:
start of quarter: 
`SELECT TIMESTAMP_TRUNC('2022-11-14 15:04:09', QUARTER);`


end of quarter: 
`SELECT TIMESTAMP_SUB(CAST(DATE_ADD(CAST(TIMESTAMP_TRUNC('2022-11-14 15:04:09', QUARTER) AS DATE), INTERVAL 1 QUARTER) AS TIMESTAMP), INTERVAL 1 SECOND)`

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little confusing, as you can't have a date which is equal to the start of a quarter and end of a quarter. If you mean you want to pull all fields where the date is between the start and end of a quarter, then you can do so in the where statement like below:

*(*This is for BigQuery by the way)*

```
where 
*your date column* >= date_trunc(current_date(),quarter) 
and 
*your date column* < date_add(date_trunc(current_date(),quarter),interval 1 quarter)
```